# How I can use mouse events with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I'm tryng to configure the list of users in a chat adding the function slide
something like this
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_down
Similar facebook, when mouse is over focus, the chat container is slowly hidden

I'm using jquery-1.8.1.min.js in the proyect and have the principal container with a id and i can configure those events like

```
$("mainContainer").someEvent(function () {
code...
}
```

I can use click, but i haven't mouse event when I put cursor inside for example.

I need .mousedown(), .mouseleave(), .mousemove(), hover(), etc.
Need I use another library JS?

I wish something like this, think the green box is the container with list of users in chat

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").mouseenter(function(){
        $("div").animate({        
            width: '+=100px'
        });
    });
  $("div").mouseout(function(){
        $("div").animate({        
            width: '-=100px'
        });
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:50px;position:fixed;right:0px;">
User1<br/>
User2<br/>
User3<br/>
User4<br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Those are all jquery mouse events... I guess I'm not clear on what the problem is.

Comment: And what's the question? Yes, jQuery has mouse events, and yes you can use them?

Comment: Yes, but i cant use $("mainContainer").mouseover() function for ex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://api.jquery.com/on/

You could do something like this:

```
$("body").on({
    click: function() {
        //...
    }
    mouseleave: function() {
    //...
    },
    //other event, etc
}, "#yourthing");
```

Comment: With this code works, thanks. I don't know was wrong or different in my application, thanks all!

Comment: Hmm not sure if you will even see this ... but just in case this can help someone: in your code you called $("div").mouseout(), that means when the mouse go to any div, it will trigger the function $("div").animate(). That one means the first div of the body ( or all, im not sure) will do the animation. You should use $(this) instead of $("div") in this second case.

Comment: Good observation Clyff, but I put this code like an example, in my code I have each DOM with his appropriate name and class. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and can use any other mouse events according to your need:

```
$("#mainContainer").on('hover', function(){
      $(selector).slideDown("slow");
  }), function(){
      $(selector).slideUp("slow");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? You might not need any JavaScript for the mouseover effect.

```css
#mainConatiner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
ul {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease;
}
#mainContainer:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainContainer">
  Hover me!
  <ul>
    <li>User 1</li>
    <li>User 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Let me know if it helps! Good luck.

Comment: +1 for a non-js answer - things that can be done with CSS should be handled with CSS esp if it can benefit from hardware acceleration!

Comment: I put an example that I wish to use in my proyect, but I'm using animate JQuery function

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has mouse based events. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/).

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qu155vd6/) where I have adapted the w3schools example to work on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

Comment: Yes, I put this example in description of my problem. But i can't use this events, only click I see in intellisence of VS

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have edited the example so that it works by moving your mouse on the element rather than clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it like this, by calling the same function for multiple events:

```
$("mainContainer").on('click mouseenter',function (event) {
    //This gives you what event happened, might be 'click' or 'mouseenter'
    var type = event.type;     
});
```